# Show hidden element inside another element on click

Tags: jquery

Follow-up on: [How to get the children of the $(this) selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306583/this-selector-and-children)

Does not work for me somehow.

http://jsfiddle.net/teKwN/1/

html

```
  <h4>
    Sometext
    <h3>
      Another text
    </h3>
  </h4>
```

css

```
h3 {
    display: none;
}
```

js

```
$('h4').live('click', function() {
    $(this).children('h3').toggle('slide');
});
```

**EDIT:
There are multiple items like h4.
http://jsfiddle.net/teKwN/4/**

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: $('h3').toggle('slow'); - not the way, since there are multiple h4s and h3s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your html is invalid so the browser tries to figure out what you meant.  If you inspect element in chrome, you will see this:

```
<h4>
    Sometext
</h4>
<h3>
    Another text
</h3>
```

Because of that, your `h4` has no children, so `$(this).children('h3')` returns no elements.

You will either need change that `h3` to something else, or change your structure and the code to reflect the change.

http://jsfiddle.net/teKwN/3/

Comment: It does have one child object.

Comment: Try inspecting it in chrome, it has no child elements unless you count the text node.  Chrome interprets it exactly as I have shown above.

Comment: <h4><h3></h3></h4> - h3 is a child of h4, same <div><span></span></div> span is a child of div?

Comment: Yes, but as I explained, `<h4><h3></h3></h4>` is invalid so the browser tries to figure out the most reasonable VALID way of interpreting it.  Chrome comes up with what I posted above, which does not have any child in h4.  I checked IE9 and it does the same.  Don't nest headings.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the exact problem is, but nesting headers probably isn't a good idea. Reorganizing your HTML with the headers as siblings in a container element seems to fix it: http://jsfiddle.net/rjzaworski/sJe3g/

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('h3').toggle('slide');
```

instead of

```
$(this).children('h3').toggle('slide');
```

Comment: That "works" but will toggle every `h3` on the page, not just the one nested within the `h4` you clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

**Check this it works fine**

```
 $('h4').live('click', function() {
        $('h3').toggle('slow');
    });
```

Comment: Sure it does, but that would toggle every `h3` on the page.

Comment: is there any smart way to do that? child frame

Comment: Yes, using `$(this)`, the way the original code does.  The issue isn't in the jquery but in the html.